# how to verify if an executable is signed by EV certificate in Windows

Tags: winapi, code-signing

With WinVerifyTrust(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wintrust/nf-wintrust-winverifytrust) I am able to verify executable signature, now I want to check if signing certificate is EV (Extended Validation) certificate, how can I do it?

Comment: You could try to use `CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy` with `CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_EV` flag to certificate verification.

Comment: An interesting thing i found is Windows driver files (e.g. c:\windows\system32\drivers\ntfs.sys) are NOT signed by EV certificate, is this expected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy works, credits to [Jeaninez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11872808/jeaninez-msft).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it solved the problem.